# How can I change the area of Ripple effect for IconButton in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I want to change the area of Ripple effect for IconButton in Jetpack Compose.

```
                IconButton(
                    onClick = { viewModel.toggleAudio() },
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .width(64.dp)
                        .height(64.dp)
                ) {
                    Icon(
                        imageVector = if (viewModel.isPlaying) Icons.Filled.Pause else Icons.Filled.PlayArrow,
                        contentDescription = if (viewModel.isPlaying) "Pause song" else "Play song",
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()

                    )
                }
```

I tried using indication on a modifier but it is not working.

```
IconButton(
                    onClick = { viewModel.toggleAudio() },
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .width(64.dp)
                        .height(64.dp)
                        .indication(
                            interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
                            indication = rememberRipple(bounded = true, radius = 30.dp)
                        )
                ) {
                    Icon(
                        imageVector = if (viewModel.isPlaying) Icons.Filled.Pause else Icons.Filled.PlayArrow,
                        contentDescription = if (viewModel.isPlaying) "Pause song" else "Play song",
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()

                    )
                }
```